# RXJS 5 .subscribe() without arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs5, subscribe

So a quick question. I've been using RxJS 5 for a few months now, and I've run into a bit of behavior that I don't really understand, as I haven't been able to look it up anywhere.

I'm in a situation where subscribing to an observable chain with simply `.subscribe();` doesn't trigger the observable.

However, if I add an onNext callback (empty or not), the observable triggers, and the chain processes: `.subscribe(() => {});`

Can anyone explain why this behavior happens?

Comment: Calling `.subscribe();` with no arguments should work. Are you able to post a more complete example?

Comment: Can you make a demo? All parameters to `subscribe()` are optional and it does work without any argument.

Comment: Checked out the very same function in the example above (now on RxJS 5.2.0, and Ionic 2.2.0), and it now processes without a body. I'll leave this thread open, in case the problem comes back.

Comment: This still does not work for me on RxJS 5.2.0 and Ionic 2.2.0. Could it be something else you changed @DarkNeuron (eg. build configuration, typescript version or sth?)

Comment: Its pretty much all the defaults, except for RxJS since I want the newest version there.

Comment: This problem has been solved on rxjs@5.4.2. Here all the details and the PR which solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608918/8090627

Comment: Nice catch. I'll close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Damian Hercun for informing that this was a now-fixed bug in RxJS 5.4.2.

> Info:
>
> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/1935
>
> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1921

Answer (score 12):

`.subscribe()` actually doesn't require any parameters, it will just create an [`emptyObserver`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e91d113e49acc9b0e12e2524040fa84cf3fa2c78/src/util/toSubscriber.ts#L20) if none are given, which should work just as well.

It is possible though, that there are issues related to this in some of the 5.0.0-beta versions - in case you are using one of those versions, you should update to a more stable release.

```js
const obs$ = Rx.Observable.of("Foo")
  .do(() => console.log("triggered!"));
  
obs$.subscribe();
obs$.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.1.1/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm also on RxJS 5.1.1. I'll try and post an example of my code.