# Empty subscribe on valueChanges in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this weird case, a subscribe that never fires if left empty.

This doesn't work:

```
this.formGroup.get('unitCount').valueChanges
.do(value => console.log(value))
.subscribe();
```

When this works fine:

```
this.formGroup.get('unitCount').valueChanges
.do(value => console.log(value))
.subscribe(() => true);
```

Here I used *() => true*, but it could anything, *false*, *void 0*, even an empty object *{}*

Why can't I leave the *subscribe()* empty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RXJS 5 .subscribe() without arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333187/rxjs-5-subscribe-without-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a older version of RxJS 5. This was a bug but is already fixed.

I can't find since what version it works correctly, but this PR could be related to this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/1935

Otherwise, show what exact RxJS version you're using.

Comment: Problem solved, I updated from rxjs@5.0.1 to rxjs@5.4.2